# How to get ContentDocument file body blob in APEX

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument

How to get ContentDocument file body blob in APEX. We can query ContentVersion but it give result like
[image]

It gives some URL but I need blob of body. How can we get them.

Comment: In query editor, you will get this. But if you do it in apex , you will actually get the blob data.Try the same query in execute anonymous

Comment: Do same query in Execute Anon and print it, you will get blob response.

Comment: @Preya you can add that as answer.

Comment: Could you tell me what query was used here? Which field in ContentVersion actually has the contents of the body of a note?

Comment: In other words: Is versionData the field that contains the body?

Comment: @cethegeek yes `VersionDate` is the field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In query editor, you will get this. But if you do it in apex , you will actually get the blob data.Try the same query in execute anonymous